# MySQL 8 migration issues with 1062 Key Duplicate Entry

Tags: mysql, migration, mysql-8.0

I am trying to import a mysql dump from a server running 5.7.41 into a new server running version: 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2. The backup is a simple dump and gzip encoded:

```
zcat /home/myuser/DB_230312_100450.sql.gz | mysql -u username dbname
```

During import the following error occures:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 5409: Duplicate entry '48506-2011-03-27 03:00:00' for key 'user_logindates.user_id'
```

The data does not show an entry at 03:00:00 for the user 48506 but only those:
[image]

The timestamp 2011-03-27 03:00:00 however exists but with different users, non of them is a douplicate. Check table returns status OK.

I also exported just this table and had a look at the insert:

```
INSERT INTO `user_logindates` VALUES (35048,'2022-01-19 19:58:08'),(...
```

It returns on direct execution the following error:

```
[22001][1292] Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2011-03-27 02:50:11' for column 'timestamp' at row 1097
```

The create table syntax is:

```
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `user_logindates` (
  `user_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

I already checked the timezone, char settings and mode. Both are running the same with the exeption of the new one missing the directive "NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER" within mode.

```
Settings:

    sql_mode=IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION
```

_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
collation_server        = utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server    = utf8

Is there anything I need to do before migrating it to MySQL 8 with a direct import from mysqldump from a 5.7 server? I can't think of a different issue as the backup "should" be OK.

Comment: To ask the obvious, is `'48506-2011-03-27 03:00:00'` a duplicate entry?

Comment: This entry does not exist, I just checked and updated the question.

Comment: I have traced the problem down to the particular problem.  The 27. of March 2011 is a time zone change in Germany. Looks like I did run into a bug. After setting another timezone I could import.